# Output from PERL script not loaded to MySQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, perl

I have a `Python script` which calls a `Perl script` to parse a file. After parsing, the `PERL` script produces an output which is to be loaded to the MySQL database in the `Python` script.

The Python script is like:

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "./parseGeneticCode.pl"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
pipe.stdin.close()
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "./makeTaxon.pl"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
pipe.stdin.close()

#Load taxon.out (output of makeTaxon.pl) in the database
sql10 = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'gene_code.out' INTO TABLE geneticcode FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (ncbi_taxon_ID, parent_ID, taxon_name, taxon_strain, rank, geneticcode_ID, mitochondrial_geneticcode_ID);"""
try:
  c.execute(sql10)
  conn.commit()
  print "\nDone uploading in taxon\n"
except StandardError, e:
  print e
  conn.rollback()
conn.close()

sql9 = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'taxon.out' INTO TABLE taxon FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (ncbi_taxon_ID, parent_ID, taxon_name, taxon_strain, rank, geneticcode_ID, mitochondrial_geneticcode_ID);"""
try:
  c.execute(sql9)
  conn.commit()
  print "\nDone uploading in taxon\n"
except StandardError, e:
  print e
  conn.rollback()
conn.close()
```

These files: `taxon.out` and `gene_code.out` are created by the perl scripts. But my Python script is giving an error:

```
(2, "File 'taxon.out' not found (Errcode: 2)")
(0, '')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "common_data.py", line 247, in <module>
    conn.rollback()
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

Neither of the files `gene_code.out` or `taxon.out` are uploaded.

Comment: Are you sure your `out` files are already generated when you are trying to load them to mysql?

Comment: I could see the files after execution.

Comment: Does it work if you specify the absolute path to the .out files?

Comment: @SlavenRezic The files are created in the same directory. Though, I will try and find if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly configure both the MySQL sever and the client in order to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL`. See the discussion [in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data-local.html).